# How does ninja detect which files to rebuild?

Tags: build, build-system, ninja

I have a directory containing a repo and a build folder. The build folder contains the complete build of objects, as triggered using `ninja`. I want thousands of copies of this directory where just one source file will be different between copies. I'm hoping to use `ninja` on these copied directories, triggering an incremental, rather than complete build, making the build much faster. However, running `ninja` in a copied directory, even with no changes applied, performs a total rebuild. The copied directory already contains all of the built objects so this is wasteful.

How does ninja detect which files have to be rebuilt and how might I go about changing the copied directory to avoid the full rebuild?

Answer (score 4):

Turns out the timestamps of copies have to be the same too. I was using `cp -r source dest` but I should have added the flag to copy timestamps: `cp -rp source dest`.